# Animation is not working for third bar in stacked bar chart in Google Charts (Visualization)

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I am using Google Charts (Google Visualization), it was working fine . But now, I am facing a weird problem in animation. It is a stacked bar chart. First two columns (bars) is animating flawlessly but third column (bar) is coming at once, animation is not working for the last bar (third column).

I have tried with total 2 bars and now 2nd bar's animation is not working (came at once). It is clear that problem is in last bar. Is it a flaw in stacked bar chart from Google Chart's end?

Here is my code:

```
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Status', awating, not_interested, interested, { role: 'annotation' }],
            ['SANDRA COOMBS', 2, 4, 2, ''],
            ['VINCENT ODA', 2, 2, 2, ''],
        ]);
        arTotal = niTotal = iTotal = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
            if (data.getValue(i, 1) != null) {
                arTotal += data.getValue(i, 1);
            }
            if (data.getValue(i, 2) != null) {
                niTotal += data.getValue(i, 2);
            }
            if (data.getValue(i, 3) != null) {
                iTotal += data.getValue(i, 3);
            }
        }
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 1,
            {
                calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: 1,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation"
            },
            2, {
                calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: 2,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation"
            },
            3, {
                calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: 3,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation"
            }]);
        var options = {
            legend: {
                position: 'none'
            },
            chartArea: { width: width, height: height, right: right },
            isStacked: true,
            orientation: orientation.orientation,
            colors: ['#008FBE', '#BE1E2D', '#00BD90'],
            fontSize: '12',
            fontName: 'OpenSans-Regular',
            hAxis: {
                viewWindowMode: 'maximized',
            },
            vAxis: {
                viewWindowMode: 'maximized',
            },
            animation: {
                startup: true,
                duration: 1500,
                easing: 'out',
            },
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("currentStatusChart"));
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', readyHandler);
        chart.draw(view, options);
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've encountered various bugs when using animation on `startup`,
specifically when a `DataView` is used to draw the chart

a workaround is to convert the `DataView` into a `DataTable` before drawing the chart,
you can use method --> `toDataTable()`

```
view.toDataTable()
```

which does seem to help in this situation,
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Status', 'awating', 'not_interested', 'interested', { role: 'annotation' }],
      ['SANDRA COOMBS', 2, 4, 2, ''],
      ['VINCENT ODA', 2, 2, 2, ''],
  ]);
  arTotal = niTotal = iTotal = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      if (data.getValue(i, 1) != null) {
          arTotal += data.getValue(i, 1);
      }
      if (data.getValue(i, 2) != null) {
          niTotal += data.getValue(i, 2);
      }
      if (data.getValue(i, 3) != null) {
          iTotal += data.getValue(i, 3);
      }
  }
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
      {
          calc: "stringify",
          sourceColumn: 1,
          type: "string",
          role: "annotation"
      },
      2, {
          calc: "stringify",
          sourceColumn: 2,
          type: "string",
          role: "annotation"
      },
      3, {
          calc: "stringify",
          sourceColumn: 3,
          type: "string",
          role: "annotation"
      }]);
  var options = {
      legend: {
          position: 'none'
      },
      //chartArea: { width: width, height: height, right: right },
      isStacked: true,
      //orientation: orientation.orientation,
      colors: ['#008FBE', '#BE1E2D', '#00BD90'],
      fontSize: '12',
      fontName: 'OpenSans-Regular',
      hAxis: {
          viewWindowMode: 'maximized',
      },
      vAxis: {
          viewWindowMode: 'maximized',
      },
      animation: {
          startup: true,
          duration: 1500,
          easing: 'out',
      },
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("currentStatusChart"));
  chart.draw(view.toDataTable(), options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="currentStatusChart"></div>
```

Comment: Please check given code again, wrongly submitted other graph chart that was simple bar graph chart and I am talking about stacked bar graph chart. It is like 3 values for one person which means 3 bars for a single entity. Sorry. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It Works and I want to tell you that 'addListener' event was also making trouble for me and I placed that after 'chart.draw(view.toDataTable(), options);'. Anyways, thanks again. cheers!